# Omega, varpi or 'double upsilon' greek symbol?

Tags: greek

How to produce symbol like this: [image: omega-pi]

Is this a special form of `\varpi`, 'double upsilon' or omega?

Comment: In my opinion, this is the default `w` in math mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the image below: it is the default `w` in math mode.

[image]